# Localizing percentages with C# and jQuery

Tags: c#, jquery

I have an ASP.NET MVC app that must work in German.

```
string percentageString = form["percentage"]; // pretend "11.3" is the value sent from the view;
decimal percentage = 0;
if (Decimal.TryParse(percentageString, out percentage))
{
  if ((percentage >= 0) && (percentage <= 100))
    model.Percentage = percentage * (decimal).01;
  else
    errors.Add("The percentage must be between 0 and 100.");
}
else
  errors.Add("Please enter a percentage.");
```

My challenge is, in English, the above works. However, in German, it fails. The first error (The percentage must be between 0 and 100) occurs. The problem is that when the `Decimal.TryParse` occurs, the `percentage` value is `113`. I suspect it has to do with the use of commas vs decimals across cultures. Yet, I'm not sure how to remedy this.

I'm using the jQuery slider in my view to set this value. Currently, it looks like this:

```
<input id="percentageSlider" name="percentageSlider" data-slider-id="percentageRateSlider" type="text" data-slider-min="0" data-slider-max="100" data-slider-step="0.1" value="@Model.Percentage" />
<input id="percentage" name="percentage" class="form-control" type="text" />

...

var percentage = @Convert.ToString(Model.Percentage.Value, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
var percentageSlider = $('#percentageSlider').slider({
  formatter: function (value) {
    return value.toFixed(1) + '%';
  },
  value: percentage,
  precision: 1
}).on('slide', 
  function (s) {
    $('#percentage').val(s.value.toFixed(1));
  })
;
```

How can I get this to work in German? Everything looks correct to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In German, the decimal point is represented by a comma and the thousands separator is a full stop/period. So 11.3 is 11 thousand 300 percent, or 113.  If someone German was asked to input a percentage, they would enter 11,3 and this should be parsed correctly.  If you want to make it work the same way regardless of the country, you could say `Decimal.TryParse(percentageString, NumberStyles.Number, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out percentage)`.